# RIA Services Server Side Exception Handling

Tags: .net, wcf-ria-services

I am trying to find out a way to handle unhandled exceptions at server side. I want control over exception handling at Domain Service level so that when any operation is called then I can log the exception and wrap it in some beautiful words to send it to the client. 
I found many ways for WCF and classic web services but nothing for RIA services.
Please provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to override the **DomainService.OnError** method as described in this [WCF RIA Services Exception Handling](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/12/08/wcf-ria-services-exception-handling.aspx)  blog entry. I've done this in a base DomainService class rather than in each individual DomainService class in my application as shown below. The **errorInfo.Error** property does not have a setter so I don't think you can replace the exception object with your own, but the `<system.web><customErrors mode="On" />` config element can prevent the details of the exception being exposed to the client.

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class DomainServiceBase : DomainService
{
    protected override void OnError(DomainServiceErrorInfo errorInfo)
    {
        Logger.WriteException(errorInfo.Error);
        base.OnError(errorInfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look for specific Errors and then throw a DomainException, which is different than the standard DomainOperationException. The DomainException has an ErrorCode in it, that can be used on the client to specify a condition that will be dealt with differently on the client.

See Kyle McClellan's response at http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/193028.aspx.
Kyle's blog is a very good resource for these types of questions as well.